# Windows Storage Space Incorrect Pool Size

Tags: windows, hard-drive, storage, storage-spaces, storage-pool

[Storage Space Configuration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZC5o.png)

I have a Storage Pool here with a 10.9 TB capacity [image above]. I have 3 spaces in the pool, with a combined capacity of less than the total pool capacity, yet I am being warned to add 2 more drives despite only using ~75% of each 5.45 TB drive in the pool.

1. D = 2TB mirrored = 4TB
2. X = 5TB split between each drive = 5TB
3. M = 1.5TB split between each drive = 1.5TB

Combined, this is 10.5 TB out of 10.9 TB. The storage space is only using 8.13 TB out of 10.9 TB.

How can this be explained? Is it a misconfiguration issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with storage spaces but it seems that the size of your volumes are fixed so that any free space that is not used by other volumes will not be available for your volume in question. Therefore your calculation of total available space cannot be applied.